# owl api state ObjectProperty relation between individuals from imports

Tags: ontology, protege, owl-api

I have an ontology instance that imports other ontology instances and I'm trying to state a relationship using an `ObjectProperty` between an individual of the import (`professors-instance` or `acm-ccs-lite-core`) and an individual of the main ontology instance (`curricula-instance`).

If I do it by hand using protege it creates:

```
<!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/lsarni/ontologies/professors-instance#Andrés_Calviño -->

<rdf:Description rdf:about="http://www.semanticweb.org/lsarni/ontologies/professors-instance#Andrés_Calviño">
    <curricula:inChargeOf rdf:resource="http://www.semanticweb.org/lsarni/ontologies/curricula-instance#Software_Architecture"/>
</rdf:Description>

<!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/lulas/ontologies/2018/acm-ccs-lite-core#10011119 -->

<rdf:Description rdf:about="http://www.semanticweb.org/lulas/ontologies/2018/acm-ccs-lite-core#10011119">
    <curricula:taughtIn rdf:resource="http://www.semanticweb.org/lsarni/ontologies/curricula-instance#Databases_1"/>
</rdf:Description>
```

But the way I'm trying to do it using owl api it creates a `NamedIndividual` in the main ontology instead and adds the relationship like this:

```
<!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/lsarni/ontologies/professors-instance#Andrés_Calviño -->

<owl:NamedIndividual rdf:about="http://www.semanticweb.org/lsarni/ontologies/professors-instance#Andrés_Calviño">
    <curricula:inChargeOf rdf:resource="http://www.semanticweb.org/lsarni/ontologies/curricula-instance#Software_Architecture"/>
</owl:NamedIndividual>
```

This is the code I'm using:

```
File file = new File("C:\\Users\\lulas\\Documents\\Curricula Ontology\\curricula-instance.owl");
OWLOntology o = man.loadOntologyFromOntologyDocument(file);
OWLDataFactory df = o.getOWLOntologyManager().getOWLDataFactory();

IRI curriculaIOR = IRI.create("http://www.semanticweb.org/lsarni/ontologies/curricula");
IRI instanceIOR = IRI.create("http://www.semanticweb.org/lsarni/ontologies/curricula-instance");
IRI profInstanceIOR = IRI.create("http://www.semanticweb.org/lsarni/ontologies/professors-instance");

OWLObjectProperty charge = df.getOWLObjectProperty(curriculaIOR + "#inChargeOf");
OWLIndividual individual = df.getOWLNamedIndividual(profInstanceIOR + "#Andrés_Calviño");
OWLIndividual course = df.getOWLNamedIndividual(instanceIOR + "#Software_Architecture");

OWLObjectPropertyAssertionAxiom objAssertion = df.getOWLObjectPropertyAssertionAxiom(charge, individual, course);
AddAxiom addAxiom = new AddAxiom(o, objAssertion);
man.applyChange(addAxiom);
```

Which is the correct way of creating a `rdf:Description`?

---

### Edit

I'm using Protege version 5.2.0 on windows.

As you both said the code was correct, I was using the incorrect IRI for one of the imported ontologies, that's why it was acting as this `NamedIndividual`s where different.

Comment: The OWL API way of creating the individual is correct. What version of Protege are you using? If I create an individual in Protege Desktop 5.2 it creates it correctly as a `NamedIndividual`.

Comment: Version 5.2.0 on Windows

Comment: @HenrietteHarmse I realize my mistake was on the IRIs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An `rdf:Description with an`rdf:about` IRI is equivalent to a named individual, so there is no real difference between the two versions. They will be parsed as the same thing by OWL API.

Not sure why Protege is outputting it in that format - as Henriette asked in the comment, which version of Protege is doing this?

Comment: Version 5.2.0, but I will test it out with the same version on Mac on monday since it tends to work better

Comment: I realized my mistake was on the IRIs